# Tokenize a string in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

In Elasticsearch tokenize all words such that if a string is **flurry's**(**ending with a apostrophe**) then i want to tokenize it as **flurry's, flurry and flurrys**. But if i have any special character including apostrophe(not ending with s like above) then i want to use my word delimiter e.g see below

> **S'sode = S, sode, Ssode, S'sode OR S-sode = S, sode, Ssode, S-sode**

My word delimiter is simply working fine but it is not working for only above case where a string end with an apostrophe and s. My word delimiter is given below

```
"my_word_delimiter" : {
        "type" : "word_delimiter",
        "preserve_original": true,
        "catenate_all": true,
        "split_on_case_change": true,
        "stem_english_possessive": false
 }
```

.I have used word delimiter filter earlier, but it is also considering **s** and i do not want single **s** in my tokenized string also i have used comma stemmer but there i didn't get **flurry's and flurrys**.

Can anyone please tell me how can i do that i don't have much idea about elasticsearch.

Till now with the help of Ketty's answer and mixing it with my word delimiter there is only one point i am stuck at how to tell word delimiter to not tokenize the string ending with **'s**  my code is given below

```
"settings": {
  "analysis": {
     "char_filter": {
        "test": {
           "type": "pattern_replace",
           "pattern": "\\b((\\w+)'s)\\b",
           "replacement": "$1 $2 $2s"
        }
     },
     "analyzer": {
              "apostrophe_analyzer": {
                    "tokenizer": "whitespace",
                    "char_filter" : ["test"],
                    "filter" : [ "my_word_delimiter", "lowercase"]
              }
     },
     "filter":{
            "my_word_delimiter" : {
               "type" : "word_delimiter",
               "preserve_original": true,
               "catenate_all": true,
               "split_on_case_change": true,
               "stem_english_possessive": false
            }
     }
  }
```

},

Comment: For that specific example, you'd probably need a possessive stemmer for English and maybe a [mapping filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.1/analysis-mapping-charfilter.html) to remove `'` character. Is that only behavior you need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest the following analyzer:

```
"analysis": {
  "char_filter": {
    "test": {
       "type": "pattern_replace",
       "pattern": "\\b((\\w+)'s)\\b",
       "replacement": "$1 $2 $2s"
    }
 },
  "filter": {
    "my_word_delimiter": {
      "type": "word_delimiter",
      "preserve_original": true,
      "catenate_all": true,
      "split_on_case_change": true,
      "stem_english_possessive": true
    }
  },
  "analyzer": {
    "my_analyzer": {
      "filter": [
        "my_word_delimiter"
      ],
      "char_filter" : ["test"],
      "type": "custom",
      "tokenizer": "whitespace"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: yeah but you forgot the first case if i will input flurry's then it will get tokeized with s also but i do not want that.

Comment: can you tell me one thing if i do not want to tokeinze some words that are ending with apostrophe and s using word delimiter how can i do that ??

Comment: I have tested that analyzer and this is what I get back for `flurry's S'sode S-sode`: `"S",
                  "S'sode",
                  "S-sode",
                  "Ssode",
                  "flurry",
                  "flurry's",
                  "flurrys",
                  "s",
                  "sode"`. To me it looks right. I suggest testing it.

Comment: Oh, wait. Now I understand.

Comment: problem is i do not want to split two string if it end with apostrophe and i only want first part of the split term not s. Also please have a relook at my question i have added my code and @keety answer.

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: have a relook at my question this will not work as for string flurry's first you will tokenize it as flurry, flurrys and flurry's now flurry's will get tokenized by word delimiter as flurry, flurry's, flurrys and s. ALso can you please tell me what does $1 and $2 do here in replacement ??

Comment: Have you tested that analyzer?

Comment: can you tell me one thing if i do not want to tokeinze some words that are ending with apostrophe and s using word delimiter how can i do that. If we can do that then my case will be solved also i read about type_table but i don't know how to use it here because for string flurry's(ending with apostrophe and s) we will not tokenize it we will leave it as it is So for string flurry's we will first get flurry and flurrys from char filter and as word delimiter will leave flurry's then my problem will be solved.

Comment: yep i have tested it already your code is same as mine which i have posted after, you can match them. Please read my comment above to see why it is not working.

Comment: It is not the same code! Please, test it exactly the way I have it in my answer.

Comment: I changed the `"stem_english_possessive"` property. In my case it is `true` because its functionality has been replaced by @keety's filter.

Comment: Ok sorry for that let me check it again.

Comment: Thanks a lot it worked now there is only one problem for flurry's i am getting flurry's, flurrys and two times flurry now i only want flurry only one time how can i do that ??

Comment: The terms are unique. You cannot get a duplicated term.

Comment: by changing replacement to $1 and $2s yep its working fine now thanks a lot man for your help

Comment: also for string 'LetsDoit' as case changed here at D my es store it as 'LetsDoit', 'Lets', 'Doit' and 'LetsDoit' why es is storing LetsDoit two times ?? do you have any idea and how can i store only one term ??

Comment: ALso terms are not unique i am getting duplicated terms as well ??

Comment: @PrakashKumar  You could just add a [unique_token_filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-unique-tokenfilter.html)  with `only_on_same_position:true` to get rid of duplicate tokens . The tokenizatin of `LetsDoit` => `LetsDoit LetsDoit Lets Doit` is expected. LetsDoit splits to `Lets` , `Doit` , since you have `catnate_all :true` it gets you the first `LetsDoit` and `perserve_original` returns the additonal  `LetsDoit` . I'll let @AndreiStefan decide if he wants to add this comment in the answer since his is the more complete answer to the problem

Comment: Hm... it seems we both are testing this in different ways. I'm using `fielddata_fields` to see the terms of the testing field. Whereas you are testing with `_analyze` API if I'm not mistaken. In my case these two approaches give different results, which is weird. More specifically with `fielddata_fields` I'm not seeing the duplicates. I'll investigate.

Comment: also one more thing if i add unique in filter my tokens are now unique can you please tell me what is the use of setting "only_on_same_position : true" instead of using only unique filter ??

Comment: From a single word at indexing time the series of token_filters (like edgeNGram) can create multiple tokens. All these tokens have the "origin" in a single word. If these tokens have duplicates then that setting will apply to them only. But let's assume you index 3 words in your field in a document. And your series of token filters maybe create duplicate tokens from all those three. If `"only_on_same_position : true"` ES will not eliminate the duplicates, because the originate from different "words" and thus, they have different positions in the original text.

Answer (score 2):

One way to achieve this is using the [pattern-replace](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-pattern-replace-charfilter.html) char filter.

Example:

```
 put test 
{
   "settings": {
      "analysis": {
         "char_filter": {
            "test": {
               "type": "pattern_replace",
               "pattern": "\\b((\\w+)'s)\\b",
               "replacement": "$1 $2 $2s"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}




get test/_analyze?tokenizer=standard&char_filter=test&text=this is flurry's test
```

Result:

```
 {
   "tokens": [
      {
         "token": "this",
         "start_offset": 0,
         "end_offset": 4,
         "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
         "position": 0
      },
      {
         "token": "is",
         "start_offset": 5,
         "end_offset": 7,
         "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
         "position": 1
      },
      {
         "token": "flurry's",
         "start_offset": 8,
         "end_offset": 15,
         "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
         "position": 2
      },
      {
         "token": "flurry",
         "start_offset": 15,
         "end_offset": 15,
         "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
         "position": 3
      },
      {
         "token": "flurrys",
         "start_offset": 15,
         "end_offset": 16,
         "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
         "position": 4
      },
      {
         "token": "test",
         "start_offset": 17,
         "end_offset": 21,
         "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
         "position": 5
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot man for your help can you please have a relook at my edited question. also can you please explain what is "replacement": "$1 $2 $2s" doing ?? what are $1 and $2

Comment: $1 and $2 are refrences to [capture groups](regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) in the regex